# Approve/reject files to sharepoint using VBA Excel

Tags: vba, sharepoint-2007, excel-2007

I'm trying to automate sharepoint file upload, checkin and approve. I'm using FP RPC to upload and checkin the file but I have no idea if I can automate approving the uploaded file. the only solution I have in mind is to create IE object and just automate the approve process with IE.visible = false.

other question is that when I try to upload powerpoint file to sharepoint meta_info is not updated that's why my files remains checkout. any idea with this scenario? so far the only work around that I had is to automate adding custom file properties so that when I upload the ppt file it will automatically have values on required properties and checkin method will work.

thanks guys!

Comment: More information. What version of Excel. What version of SharePoint.

Comment: Excel 2007 and sharepoint 2007.

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier to [use the SharePoint webservices to edit the items moderation status](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/add5e527-58ad-4dbf-b0b9-e0b1fff8e3da/?prof=required).

C# from the example.

```
public static XmlNode UpdateListItemApprove()
 {
     listservice.Lists listProxy = new listservice.Lists();


     string xml = "<Batch OnError='Continue'><Method ID='1' Cmd='Moderate'><Field Name='ID'/><Field Name='FileRef'>http://basesmcdev2/sites/tester1/approvals/KL022030.lic</Field><Field Name=\"_ModerationStatus\" >0</Field></Method></Batch>";

     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
     doc.LoadXml(xml);

     XmlNode batchNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Batch");

     listProxy.Url = "http://basesmcdev2/sites/tester1/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
     listProxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

     XmlNode resultNode = listProxy.UpdateListItems("approvals", batchNode);

     return resultNode;
}
```

[Here is an example of an update using the SOAP toolkit.](http://the-simple-programmer.blogspot.com/2010/03/set-sharepoint-meta-data-from-vba-using.html)